# how to avoid system block

Tags: objective-c, macos

I used the codes below to execute my program

```
for(int i=0;i<100000000000000000000;i++)
{
//dosomething
}
```

I want to make the computer still respond to user interaction when processing to avoid a system block.

Comment: He wants a gui's wait thread, essentially. Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1432641/how-to-do-work-outside-of-main-gui-thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Grand Central Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch). It's like BackgroundWorker/Task in .NET. [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial) also has a great tutorial.

Eg:

```
dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
dispatch_queue_t main = dispatch_get_main_queue();
dispatch_async(q, ^{
    // long running database operation
    dispatch_async(main, ^{

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The user interface is handled on the main application thread.  It seems that what you're asking for is a multi-threaded program; there are many ways to achieve that on Mac OS X, including using POSIX threads directly (`pthread_create()`, etc.).

More info:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH1-SW1